# Remove certain dashes in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a string with several dashes. Some of them (the intra-word dashes) should be kept, the rest should be removed. I manage to keep the intra-word dashes and remove most of the inter-word dashes. However, on dash at the beginning of a word are kept.

Why? How can I remove that dash to?

```
co <- "keep-this dash but remove - that -----these and these----dashes."
# remove between-word dashes
co <- gsub(" - ", " ", co)
co
# remove multiple dashes
co <- gsub("-{2}", " ", co)
co
# remove special characters but keep intra-word dashes and apostrophes
co <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", co)
co
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
gsub("(?:(-| ))-+\\s*", " ", co, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "keep-this dash but remove that these and these dashes."
```